# CanDeActivate() runs only once on same route

Tags: angular, typescript

I am facing an issue with `CanDeActivate()` in `Angular2`. The scenario is when user leaves a page from edit screen, a popup comes with Yes, No and Cancel button.
When user click on cancel button it closes the popup and when user click on no button it closes the popup with redirecting to another page where user clicks to navigate.

Suppose application has 3 modules A, B and C. Module C has edit screen. When user edit on that page and without saving user clicks on Module B. A popup comes with Yes, No and cancel button. On cancel button it remain on same page but user again click on Module B nothing happens here. If user click on Module A the popup comes.

I am stuck in this problem. I am sharing my code if anyone can help. It will be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

MyComponent.ts

```
canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean = () => {
        if (this.isEdited) {
            this.showConfirmationModal = true;
            this.canLeavePage.asObservable().first();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Can-Deactivate.guard.ts

```
export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
    canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
    canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate) {
        let can = component.canDeactivate();
        if (!can) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the latest Angular2 version?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that was fixed in 2.3.0

> router: runs guards every time when unsuccessfully navigating to the same url over and over again (#13209) (d46b8de)

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#230-2016-12-07